# Special Infantry in Rise of Nations?

Tags: rise-of-nations

How can I recruit the special units like the horse guard grenadier and Napoleon's Guard when I'm playing as the french? I would also like to know If I can get the hummers for the Americans. Is it also possible to recruit a flyut when playing as the dutch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, none of that is possible in the base game. This might however be possible in updates or extensions or through the use of cheats.

Comment: Which cheats would make it possible?